# RaphaelJS smooth rotation of objects like freeTransform

Tags: javascript, svg, rotation, raphael

I need to rotate objects in a smooth way like [Elbert F's freeTransform](http://elbertf.com/raphael/free_transform/) does.

Please anyone review my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Ef83k/55/) and help me to solve this problem.

I don't need any other code or any other plugin but some editing in [my own code](http://jsfiddle.net/Ef83k/55/)

I think some correct formula of `angle` in `move` function of code is responsible for smooth rotation of object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to add links to or describe what freeTransform is. And what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this and its a bit tricky formula of Math which helped me.
[Here is updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/Ef83k/56/)

```
var centreX = "center of rectanlge, x-coordinate", centreY = "center of rectangle, y-coordinate";
var theta = Math.atan2(centreX - dx, centreY - dy); // dx and dy are movement of mouse from the rotating element

angle =  1 * (theta * 180)/3.1415;;

element.rotate(angle, centreX, centreY);
```